# How send stream mp4 video file with net7mma library

Tags: c#, .net, video-streaming, rtsp

I am working on project that main function of it is sending mp4 file with Rtsp streaming protocol.
I want to work with net7mma library(https://net7mma.codeplex.com/)
There is no example on project page.
How can i send rtsp data with net7mma?
Anybody can send me a code exmple?
Thanks and regard

Answer (score 0):

There's plenty of examples, what your looking for is a complete system to packetize existing video files.

Your going to run into a plethora of issues especially when camera configurations change e.g. if your recording directly to MP4 and you want to switch container format to any other container format or change the properties which effect the integrity of the stream such as codec, resolution or framerate etc.

You need to design the system and requirements and then this will become a lot easier.

There should only be a single end point writing your stream to disk unless redundancy is required.

This endpoint should be storing the video in an uncompressed format if at all possible.

From there is should be encoded for viewing on demand through RTSP or otherwise.

You can also jam all of that into a single endpoint like some commercial NVR equipment does but the process doesn't really change, only cost and reliability.